# Implementing an iterator in a doubly linked circular list / ring (problem with .end())

Tags: c++, list, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement the `Iterator` class inside my `BiRing<Key, Info>` class.

What I am wondering is **how can I implement an iterator which goes through all elements of a ring**?
I have searched for solutions on the internet, but I have not been able to find any relevant ones.

Main difficulty that I am having is how to deal with `.end()` method. I have read that it's implemented by returning a pseudo-next element of the last element, but I have not seen any guide on how to do that on any custom container, let alone a doubly linked ring.

Can anyone briefly explain how those pseudo-last elements would be created in a general case and in my case and is there some other way to implement the iterator so that I am able to go through all elements of the ring?

My class (simplified):

```cpp
template<typename Key, typename Info>
class BiRing
{
private:
     struct Node
     {
         // key and info, previous and next, constructor
     };
    Node* any;

public:

     struct Iterator
     {
     private:
         Node* iter;

     public:
         Iterator(Node* any) : iter(any) {}

         void operator++() {
         if (iter == nullptr) throw ("nullptr iterator");
         iter = iter->next;
         }
         // *, == and != operators
     };

   Iterator begin() { return Iterator(any); }
   //Iterator end() { return ??? }

   // other methods
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Having realised that "pseudo-last element" literally means "another node which is processed differently under different contexts", I solved the problem by adding an empty node called `pseudoLast`.

Rest of the class `BiRing` and `Iterator` follow up on that logic. Every `Iterator` object has `Node* ptr` and `Node* toSkip` which, subsequently, allows me to check if an iterator object is used alongside correct `BiRing` object; for instance, == and != operators will throw an exception if I were to compare a biRing begin()/end() with an iterator which does not belong to that object.

In case anyone wants to check out how I have implemented it:
[Pastebin link.](https://pastebin.com/HHctMtR0)

Comment: By "ring" I'm assuming you mean your "last" element points to the "first" as its next (and vice versa). In that case, how are *you* defining `end`? What does that mean in your ring? How are you deciding which element is "first" and which is "last?"

Comment: Well in that case it is both the first and the last element. In any case, I would like to implement the iterator so that I can iterate through all elements correctly

Comment: Oh, I see. You're storing `any` as a pseudo `head`. In that case, wouldn't the "last" element just be `any->previous`?

Comment: In my case it doesn't even matter what is the first and what's the last element.  What is important to me is that I go through all elements of a sequence using the iterator, respectively.

Comment: Okay...but what element are you starting on? That must be stored somewhere. There must be some "first" and "last" to have any sense of iteration. Given how your `begin()` is written, it looks like `any` is the starting node and `any->previous` is the ending node in the iteration. What are you imagining iterating through this list looking like? Can you give some example code of how you'd like to use this?

Comment: *I have searched for solutions on the internet, but I have not been able to find any relevant ones.* [Here is a fully STL compliant ring buffer, with source code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: I did not say that it did not exist. Also, I am a beginner in C++ programming so searching for the way the Ring Buffer's author implemented Iterators is not exactly easy. But thanks for your help anyways.